# Is there a way to modify the style property of the icon when I hover over the <h3> tag?

Tags: css

```
<div class="todo-container">
    <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is--completed': todo.completed}">
        <label class="todo-title">
            <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
            <div class="checkmark"></div>                
            <h3>{{ todo.title }}</h3>
        </label>
        <div class="action-container">
            <i @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" class="action far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the icons float to right without using too much margin at the same time inline with the label.

Comment: Correct, if you want to do it in plain CSS only, that won't work with this kind of structure.

Comment: @CBroe so you're saying I should stick with the solution I found? I'm having a hard time making the icons float to the right actually that's why I have this kind of structure.

Comment: No, all I am saying is, if you want a pure CSS solution, then what you want to modify needs to be a following sibling of the h3, resp. a descendant further own inside of a sibling. If you can't work with such a structure for whatever else visual effect you need to accomplish, then you need a different solution involving JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to state exactly what effect you want as well as showing what hasn't worked. It sounds as though the real question is something like 'how do I put this icon to the right of the h3 and have it show on hovering h3'? There is more detail of course, if it just shows on hover of h3 it will disappear when you try to click it.

Comment: And placing the icon as a sibling of the h3 probably would not make much sense here to begin with - you want that to trigger a different functionality, then what clicking the h3/the label does, right? Then it should not be nested into the label, that is likely to cause accessibility issues then.

Comment: @AHaworth I tried to place the icon tag adjacent to the <h3> tag so I can solve the problem. But when I do that, that's the time I have to adjust the position of the icons and this is the part I'm having difficulties with. I'm trying not to use margin as much as possible.

Comment: Is there a reason that the icon isn't just part of the h3?

Comment: @CBroe i'll try to re-evaluate my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the icon is put as part of the h3 itself then this solves two problems.

- The icon can be shown when the h3 is hovered and it remains showing
  as the user moves to click it.
- It can be positioned correctly and when it appears it does not shift
  any other elements.

  ```
  <style>
   h3 > i {
     opacity: 0;
     }
   h3:hover > i {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   </style>
   <div class="todo-container">
       <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is--completed': todo.completed}">
           <label class="todo-title">
               <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
               <div class="checkmark"></div>                
               <h3>{{ todo.title }}<i @click="$emit('del-todo', todo.id)" class="action far fa-trash-alt"></i></h3>
           </label>
       </div>
   </div>
  ```

Comment: Yes. I tried this kind of structure. But then the problem is some todos are not equal in length (charater-wise) which gives me the option to add a property on each todo just to make their respective delete icon float to right. Which I also tried before, which makes me end up asking this question.

Comment: OK, I'm back to asking that you alter your question to state what outcome you want.